# Rounding 2.555500000000000104805053 with printf -> 2.555 or 2.556?

Tags: printf, floating-point

I tried

```
printf "%.3f\n" 2.555500000000000104805053
printf "%.3f\n" 2.555500000000000104805054
```

the result was

```
2.555
2.556
```

same with `printf "%.3f\n" 3.555500000000000104805053`

But 0.555500..., 1., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9. are correct -> x.556

What is the problem with rounding with printf?

- MacOS Ventura 13.2
- The shell is zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0), but it appears also
  in bash-3.2
- In ksh (shell) the output is identical (2.556) with both commands

Comment: Please do document your OS/shell flavours and versions. Under my GNU bash, version 5.1.16 / GNU coreutils 9.1 / Linux-5.4, your two printf produce identical output : 2,556

Comment: Double precision is only between 15 and 16 digits (53 bits). The error is in the conversion of the input string: the last 9 digits of both the inputs are only twitching the last bit of the double.

Comment: Identical output as above also under bash v 5.1.4(1) (Debian Bullseye)

Comment: @MC68020 macOS Ventura 13.2.. the shell is zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)... but it appears also in bash-3.2

Comment: in ksh (shell) the output is identical (2.556) with both commands.

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/737137/edit) the question instead of answering in comments. This way everything relevant is readily available without digging into comment section. I added the new info now, my edit will be visible when another member of the community approves it.

Comment: In ksh93, that will depend on how the C processor represents long doubles on the system. See also [Why does $((0.1)) expand to 0.10000000000000001 in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422122)

Comment: You can use `printf %.999g` to see what number the input is interpreted as. In bash, ksh93 or with GNU printf at least (not zsh), you can use `printf %la` for a hexadecimal representation (so gives you the binary number without needing too many digits contrary to decimal)